# Is a modern digital watch more capable than the Apollo Guidance Computer?

Tags: embedded, memory, cpu

I am wondering if my simple, 15 dollar Timex watch (not a smart watch) is more powerful then the Apollo Guidance Computer (looking at operations/second, RAM, storage, etc).

Comment: Powerful... such an ambiguous term.

Comment: probably not. but you cannot really compare the two specialized systems. you could compare the number of transistors, or a number of logic gates, i guess.

Comment: Digital Watches are pretty slow and dumb compared to the compiled code of AGC.

Answer (score 5):

It's very unlikely that a simple electronic watch is more powerful than the AGC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer

The AGC was a 16 bit processor (great article [here](http://sarahmzimmermann.com/Papers/TheApolloGuidanceComputer.pdf)) with a non-conventional ALU.
It ran at about 2 Mhz, and rather than running continuously, it mostly ran subroutines with a stop to readout results to the operator.

Most watches and the like are based on nibble (4 bit) cpus and run at very slow speed to get long battery life.

In the Wiki' article it's power is compared to the 6502 used in many early computers such as the Apple II.

Todays Smartphones (mostly based on ARM processors) would easily exceed the AGC capability of course.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a somewhat ambiguous one, in so much as how do you define powerful? It could be that your watch has more memory it could also be that it could do more general purpose calculations per second, but that would depend entirely on the specific watch - they aren't all made equal.

Having said that, looking at the [spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer) of the Apollo Guidance Computer (AGC), I'm not sure why any basic digital watch would have such resources. I doubt your watch could perform division and multiplication of 16bit numbers in 12 clock cycles or less.

You could compare how good they are at what they are designed to do:

- Could a basic digital watch guide you to the moon? Probably not.
- Could the AGC tell you the time? Yes.

So the watch probably couldn't do the fundamental job of the guidance computer, whereas the guidance computer could easily do the fundamental job of the watch. By that comparison, no the watch is probably not more powerful.

For what it's worth, the entire code for the AGC is actually on [Github](https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11). You could perhaps try making that run on your watch and find out?

Comment: A simple and effective comparison to answer the OP’s question.